# Is a closed set with orbit capacity zero automatically thin?

Tags: gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $G$ be a countably infinite amenable group. Let $\alpha: G\curvearrowright X$  be a continuous group action. (Mostly free and minimal, though!)

**Definition 1:**  Let $A\subset X$ be closed and $U\subset X$ open. We say that $U$ $\alpha$-dominates $A$, and write $A\lesssim U$, if there exist open sets $V_1,\dots,V_M$ and group elements $g_1,\dots,g_M\in G$ such that $A\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^M V_i$ and $\alpha^{g_i}(V_i)$ are pairwise disjoint subsets of $U$.

A closed set $A\subset X$ is called $\alpha$-thin, if $A\lesssim U$ for all non-empty open $U\subset X$.

**Definition 2:** Let $E\subset X$ be some subset. Choose some Folner sequence $F_n$ for $G$. Then the orbit capacity of $E$ is defined as
$$\operatorname{ocap}(E) = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{|F_n|} \sup_{x\in X} \sum_{g\in F_n} \mathbb{1}_E(\alpha^g(x)).$$
(This notion was introduced and studied a bit [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02810577) , where it is also shown that this is well-defined)

For closed $E\subset X$, one can in fact show that $\operatorname{ocap}(E)$ is the supremum over all $\alpha$-invariant measures evaluated at $E$. Particularly, $\operatorname{ocap}(E)=0$ means that $E$ vanishes under all $\alpha$-invariant measures.

My question is:

> If $\alpha$ is free and minimal and $E\subset X$ is closed, does $\operatorname{ocap}(E)=0$ imply that $E$ is thin?